# Foundation 6 Sticky Topbar Navigation - Triggers immediately/too early

Tags: jquery, html, css, zurb-foundation

Using Foundation 6, I am trying to create a sticky topbar that sticks to the top of the page when it is reached following [the F6 documentation](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/sticky.html#sticky-navigation).

However, it sticks immediately after scrolling the page (too early) rather than when it reaches the top: [jsbin](http://output.jsbin.com/vevajovufe)

[image: screencap]

Using purely example code, this doesn't seem to work?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="columns small-12">
      <div data-sticky-container>
        <div class="top-bar" data-sticky data-options="marginTop:0;" style="width:100%">
          <div class="top-bar-left">
            <ul class="dropdown menu" data-dropdown-menu>
              <li class="menu-text">Site Title</li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">One</a>
                <ul class="menu vertical">
                  <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="top-bar-right">
            <ul class="menu">
              <li><input type="search" placeholder="Search"></li>
              <li><button type="button" class="button">Search</button></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get this to work by setting the `data-top-anchor` to the `data-sticky-container` div.

```
<div id="item1" class="flex-child-auto" data-sticky-container>
  <div class="top-bar sticky" data-sticky data-options="marginTop:0;" style="width:100%" data-top-anchor="item1">
  </div>
</div>
```

I have created an example on [codepen](http://codepen.io/hall2cm/pen/pRMOeG).